# Trendlines in plotly - interquartile range possible?

Tags: python, plotly

I'd love to plot the 25 to 75 percentile range as a some kind of trendline. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I might be able to do that?

```
fig = px.scatter(df, "Date", y="Number of Events", color="Technology", labels={
                     "Date": "Date",
                     "Number of Events": "Number of Events",
                     "markersize": 50,
                     "s": 50,

                 }, trendline="expanding", trendline_options=dict(function="mean"), trendline_scope="overall")
```

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in option for plotting the interquartile range as a trendline. You should calculate the interquartile range (25 to 75 percentile) yourself and then plot it on the graph.

Comment: it will look sth like that https://i.imgur.com/uc5dUOl.png